# Saving game progress on iCloud: best solution?

Tags: ios, xcode, synchronization, icloud

I'm working on a new iOS game and would like to save the progress online through iCloud. The saving is fairly frequent, but they are mostly doubles and ints with scores, unlocks and NSDate numbers.

Since internet will be required to play the game, I would like to save the game only online, not locally. When the app opens it should download the saved game from the server, and when it's done, launch the game.

Online currency will be sold through IAP, so I want to make sure the progress will not be lost even if the game is deleted and reinstalled, and of course, be available on multiple devices from the same user.

What's the best way to do this? Is it possible through iCloud? Key value seems like a mess because it doesn't sync quickly with iCloud. So Core Data?

I'm not looking for code to copy and paste, but I would like to create a discussion to find out the best solution for this case, if it's iCloud, setting up my own server, etc. Everywhere I look people say different things, but so far I couldn't find the best solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 8, you might want to look at [`GKSavedGame`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSavedGame_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKSavedGame) — it manages saved games associated with a Game Center player and syncs them through iCloud.

Otherwise, direct use of iCloud APIs sounds reasonable for your use case. If you write a small, well-defined set of values, the ubiquitous key-value store is very easy to use. If your save games are more complicated, write out a property list or encode your custom objects with `NSKeyedArchiver`, then use the `NSFileManager` APIs for syncing the resulting files through iCloud.

Going for Core Data or CloudKit is also possible, but sounds like it's more complicated than your game needs.

Comment: Thanks! I will through the docs and look for GKSavedGame, sounds interesting.

Comment: It looks like GKSavedGame requires iCloud Drive to be enabled. I don't know how many users do have it enabled or even know exactly what it is.